# Toggle Class Using Aria-Expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I have the following to toggle a span element's class based on the parent's aria-expanded attr value:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('.is-accordion-submenu-parent').attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
        $(this).find(".typcn-arrow-sorted-down").toggleClass("typcn-arrow-sorted-up");
    }
})
```

Here's the structure:

```
<li class="is-accordion-submenu-parent" aria-expanded="false">
  <a>Label</a>
  <span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down"></span>
</li>
```

**EDIT**

```
  <li class="is-accordion-submenu-parent" aria-expanded="false">
    <a>Label<span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down"></span></a>
    <ul class=“nested”>
      <li class=“menu item”>…</li>
      …etc…
    </ul>
  </li>
```

A click on the a tag toggles the state, but this code doesn't work as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by targeting the *-expanded attribute and after pseudo element with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Toggling `typcn-arrow-sorted-up` will not be sufficient as you may need to toggle `typcn-arrow-sorted-down` this class as well.
Here is a working sample which shows toggling between the two classed based on the aria attribute. I have also added a button to change the attribute value to check if that works.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#ariaToggler').click(function(){
    var currValue = $('.is-accordion-submenu-parent').attr('aria-expanded');
    if(currValue == 'true'){
      currValue = 'false';
    }else{
      currValue = 'true';
    }
    $('.is-accordion-submenu-parent').attr('aria-expanded', currValue);
    checkup();
  })
  function checkup(){
    $(".typcn").removeClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-up typcn-arrow-sorted-down');
    if ($('.is-accordion-submenu-parent').attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
        
        $(".typcn").addClass("typcn-arrow-sorted-up");
    }else{
      $('.typcn').addClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-down');
    }
  }
  checkup();
})
```

```css
.typcn{
display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;

}

.typcn-arrow-sorted-down{
  
background-color:red;
}
.typcn-arrow-sorted-up{
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ariaToggler">toggle Attr</button>

<li class="is-accordion-submenu-parent" aria-expanded="false">
  <a>Label</a>
  <span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down"></span>
</li>
```

```
$(".typcn").removeClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-up typcn-arrow-sorted-down');
if ($('.is-accordion-submenu-parent').attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
  $(".typcn").addClass("typcn-arrow-sorted-up");
}else{
  $('.typcn').addClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-down');
}
```

**EDIT**

Added another sample that uses the `toggleClass` and uses the selector relative to clicked label, so this would work even for multiple.

```
$(function () {
  $('.is-accordion-submenu-parent a').click(function(){
    var currValue = $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded');
    if(currValue == 'true'){
      currValue = 'false';
    }else{
      currValue = 'true';
    }
    $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded', currValue);
    $(this).next().toggleClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-down');
    $(this).next().toggleClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-up');

  })
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('.is-accordion-submenu-parent a').click(function(){
    var currValue = $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded');
    if(currValue == 'true'){
      currValue = 'false';
    }else{
      currValue = 'true';
    }
    $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded', currValue);
    $(this).next().toggleClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-down');
    $(this).next().toggleClass('typcn-arrow-sorted-up');
    
  })

})
```

```css
.typcn{
    display:inline-block;
      height:15px;
      width:30px;

    }

    .typcn-arrow-sorted-down{
      
    background-color:red;
    }
    .typcn-arrow-sorted-up{
    background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="is-accordion-submenu-parent" aria-expanded="false">
  <a>Label 1</a>
  <span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down"></span>
</li>
<li class="is-accordion-submenu-parent" aria-expanded="false">
  <a>Label 2</a>
  <span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down"></span>
</li>
<li class="is-accordion-submenu-parent" aria-expanded="false">
  <a>Label 3</a>
  <span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but despite your successful test this doesn't function as intended. The down-arrow class is added, but not toggled in the aria-expanded=true state.

Comment: @WesleyPicotte I have added one more sample, which  i believe is your requirement. In case if you feel, its not what you need. Please consider explaining it in more detail

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've edited the HTML this snippet targets to better demonstrate the full structure. The revised snippet adds both typcn classes to ul.nested.

Comment: @WesleyPicotte Can you add text explaining what should be done. As of now clicking on the tag which i suppose is the anchor tag, you need to toggle the `aria-expanded` and the class in the span, which is working in the edit. The nested `ul` doesn't add anything to the problem statement

Comment: Correct - a click on the a element toggles the menu. The menu's plug-in targets ul.nested, which obviously holds the contents of the accordion. Your snippet looks right to me, but for whatever reason traverses to the ul, which is where I see both classes added. I'm not sure what additional info I can provide.